# Unable to access scrollToRowAtIndexpath when I segue to tableview on a UIviewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift and I am stuck at the following problem.

I have implemented a segue from a tableview (A) to a UiViewController containing a Tablebiew (B). The TableView(B) has a list of names. I want to use the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method as soon as the tableview (B) appears but it is not showing as a method in the .swift file of UiViewController. I have set the UiviewController as  delegate and datasource of the tableview (B)

[image: This is the image of my storyboard]

PS: I am trying to use the ScrollToRow in the following code.

```
import UIKit

protocol CanReceive {
    func DataReceived(book: Int, chapter: Int, bookName : String)
}

class SelectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var selectedBook = 1
var selectedChapter = 1

var delegate : CanReceive?

let chapters = [50,
                40,
                27,
                36,
                34,
                24]

let books = ["Genesis" ,
             "Exodus" ,
             "Leviticus" ,
             "Numbers" ,
             "Deuteronomy"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return books.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectorTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectorTableViewCell
    cell.bookLabel.text = biblebooks[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: you need scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated) method ?

Comment: Yes. But it is not showing in auto complete

Comment: check your xcode prefrence for autocomplete issues

Comment: The autocomplete is working fine for other methods. But ScrollToRow isn't showing up

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to use. `scrollToRow` is a tableview method, not a view controller method.

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the Code to the post. How can I use the  scrollToRow in this ?

Comment: The view controller code you have shown doesn't have a tableview property that you can reference. You need to add an `@IBOutlet` property and connect it to your tableview in Interface Builder.

Comment: @Paulw11 That fixed it. Thanks a Ton.